# What cause block to clean ContentPage on Xamarin.forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm making app with using XF PCL.

I was surprised today. 
Because contentpage is not be cleaned after popped from navigationPage.

There is Device.StartTimer() returns true, 
I understand this can be running until I return false. 
But when I stop there with using breakpoint, whole page is still remained without parent. (because it's popped)
And it's never cleaned from memory without parent.

What's the deal? 
If I stop all timer, it will be cleaned automatically?

- another question. 
  Should I put "null" to bindingContext when page is popped? Or I don't have to care about it?

Thanks.

Comment: I usually set the BindingContext to null and Dispose all the resources when popping a page.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Bruno. That's bad news for me.. It's too much work.